# lib/gdbserver Error:Permission denied

Tags: android, android-ndk, eclipse-adt

I'm trying to debug my android application in Eclipse/ADT by selecting:

Debug As->Android Native Application

However, after building I get:

```
gdbserver output:
run-as: exec failed for lib/gdbserver Error:Permission denied
Verify if the application was built with NDK_DEBUG=1
```

I am indeed building with NDK_DEBUG=1

Any ideas on how to fix this, or at least why this shows up?

I'm trying to debug the app on a droid bionic, Android Ver 4.1.2

NDK Ver: r8e

I'm not sure what extra information to provide, so please feel free to ask away.

EDIT/SOLVED!!

I needed to change the installLocation attribute in my manifest to:

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

I can't believe how much time i spent on this... :-(

Comment: Thanks... you could have put edit in answer.

Comment: Huh? The word EDIT is in my answer. See "EDIT/SOLVED".

Comment: Yes but you can answer yourself question too. it would be easier to others instead of editing questions..

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your installLocation attribute in your manifest. Try this:

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```